# Block_breaker clone in pygame with simple edge detection

Tags: python, game, pygame

I tried to make this clone of
[brick_breaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_clone) on my own
in one day. The [source code and assets](http://piyush3dxyz.github.io/block_crusher) .

However I have some concerns about the code so far:

1. It uses simple edge detection code (as if ball goes out of screen <600 or <462).
2. It uses built-in collision detection from pygame.
3. Simple array for appending blocks.

```
import pygame,sys,random,time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
blk=pygame.image.load('block.bmp')    #load blocks image
img=pygame.image.load('back.bmp')     #load background image
thung=pygame.image.load('thung.bmp')  #load player image
gameover=pygame.image.load('go.bmp')
mas=pygame.image.load('masthead.bmp')
soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('wall.wav')
back=pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')
global windowSurface


windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 462), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Simple breakout game by piyush')

class pool():
    x=1
    y=1
    dirx=''
    diry=''
    trig=0
    block=[]
    pigger=0


    def trigger(self):
        self.trig=1

    def _init_(self):
        self.x=250
        self.y=250
        dirx='left'
        diry=''
        block=[]
    def movex(self):
        if self.trig==1:
            if self.dirx=='left':
                self.x-=1
            if self.dirx=='right':
                self.x+=1
            if self.x<=0:
                self.dirx='right'
                soundObj.play()
            if self.x==600:
                self.dirx='left'
                soundObj.play()
    def movey(self):
        if self.trig==1:
            if self.diry=='up':
                self.y-=1
            if self.diry=='down':
                self.y+=1
            if self.y==0:
                soundObj.play()
                self.diry='down'
            if self.y>=410:
                self.diry='up'
                self.x=250
                self.y=250





    def drawball(self,surface):
        pygame.draw.circle(surface,(200,100,230),(self.x,self.y),13,0)

    def rev(self):
        if self.diry=='down':
            self.diry='up'
    def drawblock(self,surface):

        for blocks in self.block:
                              surface.blit(blk,blocks)


def play():
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)    

    ball1=pool() 
    pygame.init()
    for i in range(10):
            size=i*75
            ball1.block.append(pygame.Rect(size,20,40,40))
    for i in range(10):
            size=i*75
            ball1.block.append(pygame.Rect(size,60,40,40))
    for i in range(10):
            size=i*75
            ball1.block.append(pygame.Rect(size,100,40,40
    ball1.x=400
    ball1.y=200
    ball1.dirx='left'
    ball1.diry='up'
    ball1.pigger=1

    a=300
    b=340
    while True:
        windowSurface.fill((25,25,25))


        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        a=pos[0]
        for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


             if event.type==KEYUP:
                 if event.key==K_LEFT:
                     a-=30
                 if event.key==K_RIGHT:
                     a+=30
                 if event.key==ord('a'):
                     pigger=0


        thunge=pygame.Rect(a, b, 120, 10)
        ball=pygame.Rect(ball1.x, ball1.y, 10, 10)  
        windowSurface.blit(img,(0,0))
        windowSurface.blit(thung,thunge)
        ball1.drawball(windowSurface)
        ball1.movex()
        ball1.movey()
        ball1.trig=1
        ball1.drawblock(windowSurface)
        windowSurface.blit(mas,(-20,410))
        if thunge.colliderect(ball):
            print("collision detecte")
            ball1.rev()
            soundObj.play()

        for blok in ball1.block:
            if ball.colliderect(blok):
                ball1.block.remove(blok)


        pygame.display.update()





play()
```

Answer (score 8):

- First off, according to [this online tool](http://pep8online.com/), you have `~119` PEP8 violations. So, for my first tip, I'm going to reccomend reading [Python's official style guide, PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The style guide essentially tells you how to format your code, so I'm not going to give you any tips on that in this answer.
- Secondly, your `pool` class seems weird, partially because it seems like you don't necessarily need it, like it's just a static class with variables, and functions that modify those variables. In that case, I'd recommend abandoning the `pool` class completely, and just having global variables, with functions that modify those variables.
- On your `pool` class again, you've misspelled `__init__` and put `_init_` instead.
- Sorry if this sounds rude, but some of the names that you've given your variables and functions are **awful**. I mean, I have no idea what the variable `pigger`, or `thung` does just by looking at it. You also shouldn't abbreviate already short variable names. For example, `block`, does **not** need to become `blk`.
- Avoid importing multiple files on one line. This helps weed out certain errors if one of the imported files isn't working correctly. You should import modules like this.

---

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import random
```

---

- Your `play` function could be separated into multiple functions, like a `create_blocks` function, or `check_for_quit`.
- You should define `SCREEN_WIDTH` and `SCREEN_HEIGHT` variables. This gets rid of *"magic numbers"*, and helps with overall readability.
- Finally any variables with values that don't change should be constant. For example, `gameover` should be `GAME_OVER_IMAGE`.

Anyways, I hope this helped!